# Why does Svelte goto statement doesn't work on root?

Tags: svelte, goto

Ok, so I am trying to build a simple login page with a Svelte app, for now it have almost no logic at all, but I am just trying to play a little bit with the Svelte store. But I am encountering a small problem with the `goto` function.
So this is my file login page and it is store under `routes/login`

```js
<script>
    import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
    import { isAuthenticated, login } from "./auth";

    let authenticated = false;
    isAuthenticated.subscribe(value => authenticated = value);
    $: if(authenticated) {
        console.log("here");
        goto("/");
    }
</script>

<form>
    <button on:click={() => {login("", "")}}>Login</button>
    <a href="/">test</a>
</form>
```

So each time I am clicking on the button I am setting the user as logged in like this :

```js
interface User {
    email: string
}

export const isAuthenticated : Writable<boolean> = writable(false);
export const user : Writable<User> = writable<User>(undefined);
export const emptyUser : User = { email: '' };
/**
 * Function to handle the login logic of the user
 * @param email 
 * @param password 
 */
export function login(email : string, password : string) : null {
  // Call the login service on the backend and in function of
  // the result, set the user to the authenticated user


  isAuthenticated.set(true);
  user.set({ email });
  return null;
}
```

The if statement is executed, so it is not the problem. But I can't understand why the goto statement doesn't redirect to the root path. I even try to change the goto to a "/test" path and it worked...

I add a link to "/" to see if that would also not work, but it is working...

So I basically don't know why the goto function doesn't redirect me to the app root. If you have a solution I will gladly accept it.

Btw I already try to do it with the native way:

```js
window.location.assign("/");
```

and it worked but it is not really the native way to do it in Svelte so I don't really wanna use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, note that the `goto` function can only be called client-side. Therefore, it is recommended to check whether the code is being executed in the browser before using this function:

```js
$: if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // Your code
}
```

In addition, if you are using a writable store to manage authentication state, you may need to add permanent storage to persist the authentication state across different pages. To achieve this, you can change your `isAuthenticated` store to a persistent store using the `persist` function from the [@macfja/svelte-persistent-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@macfja/svelte-persistent-store) package:

```js
import { isAuthenticated, user, emptyUser } from "./store.js";

export function logout() {
  // Perform logout logic
  // Once logged out, reset the isAuthenticated and user store values
  isAuthenticated.set(false);
  user.set(emptyUser);
}
```

By resetting the store values, you ensure that the authenticated variable is updated accordingly.